# Tenant and Site Setup - Description of Modules

Tags: sxa

I am setting up a new Tenant and Site and am looking for an explanation of the different Modules that can be installed against the Tenant / Site.

I want to only install the minimum required modules for my use case so as to not clutter the Content Editor and Experience Editor with things that will never be used.

Is there any documentation or information available as to what these modules provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method that I've found is to go through the `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator` items and see what each feature will scaffold when it gets installed against a Site or Tenant.

The great advantage of this method is that it is somewhat self-documenting for the version of SXA that you're using. An example from SXA 1.8:

[image: SXA screenshot]

We can see that if you were to install the Compliancy feature against the Site, it would add

- Privacy Warning datasource item
- Privacy Warning rendering on the Meta available renderings (in toolbox)
- Modifies the Settings item's insert options to add the datasource item

More info on how these settings work is available [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-modules-to-site-and-tenant-scaffolding.html).

Answer (score 2):

I used a Sitecore-provided "SXA showcase" site which you can download and install [from here](https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/e44ra1p6ivrqe2jsfehbyawubmmsjagy). It provides a reference site with all of the out of the box variants, amongst other things. It requires Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

I made this list by going through the Feature and Foundation modules in SXA for Sitecore 9.3:

**Tenant -  those marked * are also addable at the Site level.**

```
*Composites (Feature) - adds Composite Theme base template (field) to Settings
Content Validation (Foundation) - adds _HasValidUrlName base template to Page template
Error Handling (Feature) - adds _ErrorHandling base template to site Settings (404 and 500 pages)
*Forms (Feature) - adds WFFM form wrapper, Sitecore form wrapper and Forms Script renderings
*JSON (Feature) - adds JSON Layout at tenant level
Navigation (Feature) - adds Link, Navigation, Breadcrumb, Archive, Link List components
*Redirects (Feature) - adds Redirect as insert option under Home and Page templates
Search (Feature) - adds all the search related features
*Security (Feature) - probably enables the Add Security script
*SiteMetadata (Feature) - adds to pages base templates: Custom Metadata, Open Graph, Seo Metadata, Sitemap, Twitter ,Metadata and settings for Favicon, Robots, Sitemap
Sticky Notes (Feature) - adds Sticky Notes base template to Pages, Page Design and Partial Design
*Taxonomy (Feature) - adds Taggable base template to Pages
```

**Site level - those marked * are also addable at Tenant level and probably have to be added there first.**

```
Accessibility (Feature) - adds Skip links component
Analytics (Feature) - adds Google Analytics rendering
Compliancy (Feature) - adds Privacy Warning rendering
*Composites (Feature) - adds the following components - Accordion, Carousel, Flip, Tabs plus the Snippet rendering
Content Tokens (Feature) - adds Content Tokens folder to site Data folder
Context (Feature) - adds the Site Selector and Language Selector renderings
Creative Exchange (Feature) - adds the CLI theme?
Engagement (Feature) - adds Discus and Facebook Comments renderings
Events (Feature) - adds Event List, Event Calendar renderings and Events data folder
*Forms (Feature) - adds WFFM form wrapper, Sitecore form wrapper and Forms Script renderings
Generic Meta Rendering (Feature) - adds HTML Snippet component
Geospatial  (Foundation) - adds Maps Provider, Event Types, POIs settings
*JSON (Feature) - adds JSON Content, JSON List, JSON Results renderings, and CORS settings
Layout Service (Feature) - adds Page layout as JSON rendering
Local Datasources (Foundation) - adds Datasource Configurations to settings
Maps (Feature) - adds Map component
Media  (Feature)- adds File List, Flash, Gallery, Image, Media Link, Playlist, Image (Reusable), Video components
Overlays (Feature) - adds Overlays folder under site Home
Page Content (Feature) - adds Title, Page Content, Page List, Pagination, Plain HTML, Promo, Plain HTML (Reusable), Rich Text (Reusable), Rich Text, Field Editor  components
Page Structure (Feature) - adds Container, Divider, Splitter (Columns), Splitter (Rows), Toggle, IFrame, Edit Mode Panel components, plus IFrame and Toggle data folders
*Redirects (Feature) - adds Redirects under site Settings
*Search renderings (Feature) -  adds all the search related components
*Search settings (Foundation) - adds Facets, Item Queries, Scopes  settings folders
*Security (Feature) - adds Login and Logout renderings and Security data folder
*Site Metadata (Feature) - adds Browser Title, CanonicalUrl, Custom, Favicon, Open Graph, Seo, Twitter, Viewport components
Social (Feature) - adds AddThis, Feed, Social Media Share, Twitter components 
*Taxonomy (Feature) - adds Tag List, Tag Cloud renderings ; Tags data folder, SxaTags facet
```